# $http header 'Content-Type' not appending in the header - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, http, http-headers, http-get, restangular

I'm using `$http` to do a GET request and I wanted to append `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` in the header. If I don't append this header `415 (Unsupported Media Type)` error is thrown.

I'm using Apache 2.2.13 with ProxyPass, in which **I DO NOT** say 
`RequestHeader append Content-Type "application/json"`. However if I put the `RequestHeader` configuration in apache `$http.get` works fine and the `'Content-Type'` is also appended.

**Scenario 1 :**
Using `$http`, trying GET request

*Request :*

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json'},
    url: '/items/?customerId=5656'
});
```

*Chrome Network Tab :*

[image]

---

**Scenario 2 :**
Using `Restangular`, trying the same GET request

*Request :*

```
Restangular.setDefaultHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
Restangular.setBaseUrl('/items')
Restangular.all('').getList({customerId: '103020'}, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
```

*Chrome Network Tab :*

[image]

The other interesting part here is, when I do some mistakes on the Request Header like,
`Restangular.setDefaultHeaders({'Contentttt-Type': 'application/json'})`
and try Scenario 1, I notice the following in the Chrome Network Tab.

[image]

---

**Scenario 3 :**
Using `jQuery` ajax, trying the same GET request

*Request :*

```
$.ajax({
         url: "/items/?customerId=103020",
         type: "GET",
         beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');},
         success: function() { alert('Success!'); }
      });
```

*Chrome Network Tab :*

[image]

**Questions :**

1. Is it necessary to add `RequestHeader append Content-Type "application/json"` in Apache configuration? But if I add that I get 415 errors on `POST` requests.
2. What is the problem with AngularJS and Restangular that it won't append `Content-Type` headers to its network calls on `GET`?
3. What is the best solution to solve this? I have tried out all the combinations but no luck!

**Versions :**

Angular : 1.2.22

Restangular : 1.4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting a Content-Type header field on an HTTP request that doesn't have a request body (such as GET) is non-sense.

Maybe what you *really* want is set "Accept"?

Comment: I'm sure that I wanted to add `'Content-Type'` but I agree it is not required for `GET`. So is that something has to be changed in API side?

Comment: Agreed with you. You can set the `Accept` header on your `GET` requests so that you force the `application/json` value. Please check my answer for more details.

Comment: @yashhy if the API really requires a Content-Type on GET it is broken and you should report a bug.

Comment: okay thanks for your inputs will check with the APIs. I guess angular by default suppresses the 'Content-Type' for `GET` request.

Answer (score 4):

On the one hand, with the `$http` service, you can override or add your headers using `$httpProvider` when calling the `config` method on your module :

```
module.config(function($http) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = { 'Content-Type : 'application/json' };
});
```

On the other hand, with the `GET` method, if your API is really RESTFull, only the `Accept` header should be set since you are not sending `JSON`data.

Thus, use the above code for your `PUT`/`POST` methods and force the `Accept` header for the `GET`method:

```
module.config(function($http) {
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = { 'Content-Type : 'application/json'};
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = { 'Content-Type : 'application/json'};
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = { 'Accept : 'application/json'};
});
```

**EDIT 1:**

If you want to force the `content-type` in a `GET` request, you have to add a blank data :

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    data:'',
    dataType:'json',
    headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json'},
    url: '/items/?customerId=5656'
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried this way too. But when we give a `GET` request the 'Content-Type' is not appended. May be the angular by default suppresses the 'Content-Type' for `GET` request!

Comment: @yashhy Please, refer to the EDIT and try to add a blank data so that you can force Angular to append the `content-type` header

Comment: found the place https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.22/src/ng/http.js#L707 here when there is no request data, content-type is deleted :)

Comment: its works good when we have an empty data on GET, since its now understood that angular strips it out :)

Comment: @yashhy Ok. I'm glad it helped. Please, don't forget to check one of the answers that suited your needs.

Comment: Wow. It's an interesting exercise to force a framework to do something stupid. I'd concentrate on fixing the other side, though (if it actually needs to be fixed and this isn't just a misunderstanding).